# Python how to get a word in string via specified character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = "I only want the $1000"
print(get_word_containing("$")
output: $1000
```

How would I get the whole word within a string by a character within that word to work like shown above?

Comment: Do you want words with `'$'` as the first character or `'$'` can be anywhere in the word?

Comment: In the case of what I'm using it for, its first, but I would prefer if the word can be found with '$' anywhere in the word.

Answer (score 3):

Your function can be as simple as follows:

```
def get_word_containing(string, char):
    words = [word for word in string.split() if char in word]
    return words

string = "I only want the $1000"
print(get_word_containing(string, "$"))
```

Output:

```
['$1000']
```

Answer (score 1):

I will modify @Biplob function a little to print the strings instead:

```
def get_word_containing(myStr, char):
    for x in myStr.split():
      if char in x:
        print(x)

mystring = "I only want the $1000"
get_word_containing(mystring, "$")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

a = "I only want the $1000"

list = re.findall("[$]\w+", text)

print(list)
```

Above code will give you array of all words starts with $ in your string

Comment: Not really.  Your answer will give any _substring_ which has `$` followed by one or more word characters.  And your answer is not really a function as it hard codes the regex pattern.

Comment: thanks Tim for correcting my mistake, have modified code so that char will not be hardcoaded, also verified it by executing it manually and it giving me array of words starts with $

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def get_word_containing(myStr, char):
    list = re.findall("["+char+"]\w+", myStr)
    return list;

mystring = "I only $200 want the $1000"
ouput = get_word_containing(mystring, "$")
print(ouput);
```

So it will give us ['$200', '$1000']